# Sharepoint hide items in menu

Tags: sharepoint, moss, menu, wss-3.0

Is there a way to hide: "Edit Item" / "Manage Permissions" / etc in a Sharepoint List?
I want to avoid to modify CORE.JS, maybe a JQuery hack/tweak?
Ive researching but I see nothing clear.

Comment: You only see these items if you have relevant permissions for the said list. Why don't you just turn down the permissions for the users that you don't want to have this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only see these items if you have relevant permissions for the said list. Why don't you just turn down the permissions for the users that you don't want to have this functionality?

Comment: set permissions before attempting JS hacks, its much more maintainable and scalable.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768565.aspx) on MSDN to do it javascript's way.

Comment: And they recommend modifying one of the files in the "12 hive"!! What are MS doing?

Comment: @Alex, not quite that. You copy&paste original file, make modifications, create custom masterpage, or better use the same masterpage, but use DelegateControl "AdditionalPageHead" to include your custom js. And then use a feature to activate/deactivate custom javascript. Yippe : http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2008/11/20/sharepoint-2007-and-jquery-1.aspx